# Having trouble with a Linq Join statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

So I have the following Linq query:

```
var comb1 = (from m1 in _modified
                     join o1 in _original on m1.custom_field_option_id equals o1.custom_field_option_id
                     from e1 in _existing
                     .Where(row => (m1.custom_field_option_id == row.custom_field_option_id || m1.custom_field_option_id == 0)
                         && row.custom_field_id == m1.custom_field_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { m1, o1, e1 }).ToArray();
```

In List `_modifed` I have two items. In List `_original` I have one item. The second item in `_modified` is a new insert record. `_original` does not contain this record and nor does `_existing`.

The new record is not being included in my combined array. The custom_field_option_id of the new record is currently 0 so I added to my where clause:

```
|| m1.custom_field_option_id == 0
```

But that didn't help.

How do I change this query to include the new record in `_modified`?

Comment: Should `_mod.custom_field_id` be m1.custom_field_id`, or am I missing something?

Comment: I changed _mod.custom_field_id to m1.custom_field_id and updated my answer. Still having the exact same issue, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Also, what is the end result that you're looking for? It would make it easier to try to help with an answer.

Comment: Well I am trying to include the 2nd record in _modified that is currently being excluded is really the goal. My end result would contain two records where it currently only contains one.

Comment: @BrianOgden have you tried left outer join like in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless i am missing sommething:
    join o1 in _original on m1.custom_field_option_id equals o1.custom_field_option_id
is a hard join to whatever is in _original.

Could it be that the row is not present because the row is not in _original?

Comment: That seems the case, I thought I was taking advantage of  .DefaultIfEmpty() properly to create a left outer join

Comment: Let's see if we can make this outer

from m1 in _modified join o1 in _original on m1.custom_field_option_id equals o1.custom_field_option_id

from m1 in _modifiled
     o1 in _original.Where(row => row.custom_field_option_id == m1.custom_field_option_id).DefaultIfEmpty()

Conversely, just add a dummy row to _original for all missing rows. Ether way you will get your join.

Comment: Let's see if we can make this outer

    from m1 in _modified
    join o1 in _original on m1.custom_field_option_id equals o1.custom_field_option_id

to

    from m1 in _modifiled
         o1 in _original.Where(row => row.custom_field_option_id == m1.custom_field_option_id).DefaultIfEmpty()

OR

Conversely, just add a dummy row to _original for all missing rows. Ether way you will get your join.

Comment: remove the  || m1.custom_field_option_id == 0